# pm2 in systemd not actually starting processes

Tags: systemd, node.js, amazon-linux, pm2

I'm having an issue where I'm running `pm2` as `pm2-root` under `systemd` (this is on Amazon Linux2023). The daemon runs fine, and if a process dies, it restarts it fine. However, if the server reboots, `pm2-root` restarts, and it *says* it's restarted all of the processes, but it hasn't. For example:

```
# pm2 ls
┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 3  │ IDAP Dev           │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 4  │ IDAP Website       │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 10 │ Mirovoy NextJS     │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 5  │ Reanthropize       │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 6  │ Reanthropize Stage │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 1  │ lp-api             │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 9  │ url-shortener      │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │
└────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

I've already manually intervened with ids 3, 9, and 10, but let's look at 1 (full `desc` at end):

```
# pm2 desc 1
 Describing process with id 1 - name lp-api 
┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                                     │
│ restarts          │ 0                                                          │
│ uptime            │ 23h                                                        │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/lp-api-1.pid                               │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                          │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                          │
│ created at        │ 2022-08-23T14:26:17.285Z                                   │
└───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

There's absolutely nothing in the logs:

```
# pm2 logs 1
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [1] process (change the value with --lines option)
/root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-out.log last 15 lines:
/root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-error.log last 15 lines:
```

But it's definitely not running:

```
# ll /root/.pm2/pids/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 Sep 26 10:09 Mirovoy-NextJS-10.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 Sep 26 00:01 url-shortener-9.pid
# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 9292
#
```

Yet if I now manually restart it:

```
# pm2 stop 1
[PM2] Applying action stopProcessId on app [1](ids: [ '1' ])
[PM2] [1](1) ✓
# pm2 delete 1
[PM2] Applying action deleteProcessId on app [1](ids: [ '1' ])
[PM2] [lp-api](1) ✓
# cd /mnt/data/www/vhosts/chrisrichardson.info/landing-page-api // cd to exec cwd
# pm2 start npm --name lp-api -- run prod // run script args
```

all is good

```
# ll /root/.pm2/pids/
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 Sep 26 10:09 Mirovoy-NextJS-10.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 Sep 26 11:19 lp-api-11.pid // <- PID now here
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 Sep 26 00:01 url-shortener-9.pid
# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 9292
node      79177            root   19u  IPv6 410747      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
```

How do I get it to actually start the processes on system reboot, instead of just pretending/thinking it does?

**Note**: I've also included the full desc of it after manual intervention, and the only thing I see is that there's some `env` divergence, but I don't see how that's causing the problem.

### Appendix

Full output of `pm2 desc 1`:

```
 Describing process with id 1 - name lp-api 
┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                                     │
│ name              │ lp-api                                                     │
│ namespace         │ default                                                    │
│ version           │ N/A                                                        │
│ restarts          │ 0                                                          │
│ uptime            │ 24h                                                        │
│ script path       │ /bin/npm                                                   │
│ script args       │ run prod                                                   │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-error.log                           │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-out.log                             │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/lp-api-1.pid                               │
│ interpreter       │ node                                                       │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                                        │
│ script id         │ 1                                                          │
│ exec cwd          │ /mnt/data/www/vhosts/chrisrichardson.info/landing-page-api │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                                  │
│ node.js version   │ 17.9.0                                                     │
│ node env          │ N/A                                                        │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                          │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                          │
│ created at        │ 2022-08-23T14:26:17.285Z                                   │
└───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 Divergent env variables from local env 
┌──────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ HOSTNAME     │ ip-10-0-4-227.eu-cen │
│ SUDO_COMMAND │ /bin/su              │
│ LANG         │ en_GB.UTF-8          │
│ LS_COLORS    │ rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=3 │
│ PATH         │ /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin │
│ _            │ /bin/pm2             │
└──────────────┴──────────────────────┘

 Add your own code metrics: http://bit.ly/code-metrics
 Use `pm2 logs lp-api [--lines 1000]` to display logs
 Use `pm2 env 1` to display environment variables
 Use `pm2 monit` to monitor CPU and Memory usage lp-api
```

Full output of `desc` after manual intervention:

```
# pm2 desc 11
 Describing process with id 11 - name lp-api 
┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                                     │
│ name              │ lp-api                                                     │
│ namespace         │ default                                                    │
│ version           │ N/A                                                        │
│ restarts          │ 0                                                          │
│ uptime            │ 7m                                                         │
│ script path       │ /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm                  │
│ script args       │ run prod                                                   │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-error.log                           │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/lp-api-out.log                             │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/lp-api-11.pid                              │
│ interpreter       │ node                                                       │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                                        │
│ script id         │ 11                                                         │
│ exec cwd          │ /mnt/data/www/vhosts/chrisrichardson.info/landing-page-api │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                                  │
│ node.js version   │ 18.17.1                                                    │
│ node env          │ N/A                                                        │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                          │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                          │
│ created at        │ 2023-09-26T11:19:35.717Z                                   │
└───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 Actions available 
┌────────────────────────┐
│ km:heapdump            │
│ km:cpu:profiling:start │
│ km:cpu:profiling:stop  │
│ km:heap:sampling:start │
│ km:heap:sampling:stop  │
└────────────────────────┘
 Trigger via: pm2 trigger lp-api <action_name>

 Code metrics value 
┌────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ Used Heap Size         │ 15.67 MiB │
│ Heap Usage             │ 90.12 %   │
│ Heap Size              │ 17.38 MiB │
│ Event Loop Latency p95 │ 1.13 ms   │
│ Event Loop Latency     │ 0.23 ms   │
│ Active handles         │ 5         │
│ Active requests        │ 0         │
└────────────────────────┴───────────┘
 Divergent env variables from local env 


 Add your own code metrics: http://bit.ly/code-metrics
 Use `pm2 logs lp-api [--lines 1000]` to display logs
 Use `pm2 env 11` to display environment variables
 Use `pm2 monit` to monitor CPU and Memory usage lp-api
```

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with pm2, but looking at your description, it seems like all that it does is exactly duplicate the service management and monitoring that systemd itself could already do?

Comment: Probably yes, but PM2 seems to be the ... way ... to manage node services in production. If you have a good/easy guide on using systemd for the same thing, I'm totally willing to go that route, but don't want to become a systemd expert :)